# Retrofit HTTP 503 Error when Specifying Author in URL

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

I'm currently facing an issue where I encounter an error while using Retrofit to make an HTTP request to a specific URL and specifying the author as a path parameter.

The Code

```
@GET("q=inauthor:\"{author}\"")
suspend fun searchBookbyAuthor(
    @Path("author") author: String
)
```

When making a request using the searchBookbyAuthor function, with the author parameter passed as a path parameter, I encounters an HttpException with a status code of 503 (Service Unavailable). The desired behavior is to search for books by a specific author using the Google Books API.

Comment: error 503 means there is error on server side. please check from postman

Comment: HttpLoggingInterceptor loggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        //to show log
//            loggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.NONE);
        OkHttpClient.Builder httpClientBuilder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

try logging errors so that you can find the exact problem